# ASP.Net - WebForms - How to avoid several Page_Load events when a link is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, postback, pageload

I am working on website using ASP.Net C# WebForms Framework 3.5
I am using Master page for design, and inside Master page I have two user Controls for Header & Footer.
When a user logs in, in Header Control, there is a link to Logoff and onClick event we have written logoff code in cs file.

When we click it, .net will call WebForm's page_load event, then master pages's page_load event, then page_load events of all user controls used in master page and then finally the click event will be called.

How can we avoid this? I want to avoid page_load events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

asp.net architecture works like that .you cant change that.

But you can follow a different approach.

Instead of postback when you click on a button you can call a Webserivice directly from the client side(from javascript).

Or you need to follow asp.net MVC.

Answer (score 3):

You can't avoid this, because of the way the [asp.net page life-cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) works. However, you should put your code under `!IsPostBack`

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
      // put your code here..
   }
 }
```

Comment: I know we can do this way, but there are few things which can't be put in 

if (!IsPostBack) { // put your code   }

Answer (score 1):

use the following code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(!IsPostBack)
{
//code part
}
}
```

Comment: I know we can do this way, but there are few things which can't be put in if (!IsPostBack) { // put your code } .. What to do with those?